# Is a differentiable probability density function bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $g$ be a lebesgue probability density function, differentiable, such that $\sup_x|g'(x)| < \infty.$

Is $g$ bounded?

Comment: Probability density with respect to the Lebesgue measure?

Comment: Yes. Added this to the conditions. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $M := \sup_x \lvert g'(x)\rvert$. Let $n \geqslant 2$. Suppose there exists an $x_n$ with $g(x_n) = n$. Let $x_{n-1}$ be a closest point to $x_n$ with $g(x_{n-1}) = n-1$ (since $g$ is continuous, and $\int g(x)\,dx = 1$, there exist points with $g(x) = n-1$, as $\liminf\limits_{x\to\pm\infty} g(x) = 0$). Without loss of generality, $x_{n-1} < x_n$. Let 
$$
  y_n = \min \{ x : x > x_{n-1}, g(x) = n\}.
$$ 
Then $n-1 \leqslant f(x) \leqslant n$ for $x_{n-1} \leqslant x \leqslant y_n$, and

$$1 = g(y_n) - g(x_{n-1}) = \int_{x_{n-1}}^{y_n} g'(x) \,dx \leqslant (y_n - x_{n-1})\cdot M,$$

hence $\lambda(\{x : n-1\leqslant g(x) \leqslant n\}) \geqslant \frac{1}{M}$, where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure. But since $\int g(x)\,dx = 1$ we have 
$$
  (n-1)\cdot \lambda(\{x : n-1\leqslant g(x) \leqslant n\}) \leqslant \int g(x)\,dx = 1,
$$ 
hence $\frac{1}{M} \leqslant \frac{1}{n-1}$ or $n \leqslant M + 1$.

Comment: Daniel, could you explain why $(n-1)\cdot \lambda(\{x : n-1\leqslant g(x) \leqslant n\}) \leqslant \int g(x)\,dx$ please

Comment: Because $(n-1)\cdot \lambda(X_n) = \int_{X_n} (n-1)\,dx \leqslant \int_{X_n} g(x)\,dx \leqslant \int_\mathbb{R} g(x)\,dx$, where $X_n = \{x : n-1 \leqslant g(x) \leqslant n\}$. The first inequality because $g(x) \geqslant n-1$ on $X_n$, the second because $g(x) \geqslant 0$ everywhere.